# how to print something inside a list without the '[]' and ',' in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

When user input 'saya suka makan pisang', the expected output is 'i like eat banana'.
But now what I'm getting is [i,like,eat,banana].
How should i fix that?

these are my facts:

```
words(saya,i).
words(makan,eat).
words(pisang,banana).
words(suka,like).

translation(X,Y):-
    words(X,Y).
translation(X,Y):-
    words(Y,X).
translation(X,X).

translate([], []).
translate([H|T], [H1|T1]):-
             translation(H, H1),
             translate(T,T1).

prolist([],[]).
prolist(SL,[W|T]):-
    split(SL,WL,R),
    name(W,WL),
    prolist(R,T).

split([],[],[]).
split([32|T],[],T).
split([H|T],[H|T2],R):-
    split(T,T2,R).  

run:-
    nl,write('Enter One sentence or word (English or Malay):'),
    read(X),end(X),
    nl.

end(X):-    
    X=q->write('SESSION END. THANK YOU. ');
    name(X,SL),prolist(SL,List),translate(List,W),
    nl,
    write('Translated as:'),
    write(W),
    nl,
    run.
```

Comment: In Prolog a List always has seperated Objects with ',' and to notify its a list it has [] brackets. You could work around it check http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/3 to remove brackets.

The first parameter is your List, the second is the Seperator and the Last one would be your Atom which your want to use as output in this case

Comment: not really understand prolog, can you write me some code pls?

Comment: What is your inital predicate? Are you using `translation([saya,suka,makan,pisang],X)` ?

Edit: I see, you are using it as run and end and at the end you push it via write.

Comment: @A.A.mind to help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112352/how-to-translate-saya-to-i-and-saya-to-i-in-prolog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List elements in Prolog are always seperated via ',' and to signalize that they are lists they are wrapped with "[List]"

However you can convert your List to an atom and remove your brackets and ',' by using in your case:

`atomic_list_concat(List, ' ', W)`

List is the List you are using, ' ' is the seperator you want, in this case you dont want any, and W is the output atom you will get for this predicate.
The predicate and its parameters are:

`atomic_list_concat(+List, +Separator, -Atom)`

All you have to do is to replace your end(X) predicate with

```
end(X):-    
X=q->write('SESSION END. THANK YOU. ');
name(X,SL),prolist(SL,List),translate(List,K), atomic_list_concat(K, ' ', W),
nl,
write('Translated as:'),
write(W),
nl,
run.
```

and it will work as intended

for more look up: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/3

Comment: great explanation, works like a charm, this is exactly what I want. Thx a lot

Comment: mind to help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112352/how-to-translate-saya-to-i-and-saya-to-i-in-prolog

Answer (score 0):

In win-Prolog version, you can substitute the `atomic_list_concat(List, ' ', W)` into the cat/3 predicate, for instance:

```
words(saya,i).
words(makan,eat).
words(pisang,banana).
words(suka,like).

translation(X,Y):-
    words(X,Y).
translation(X,Y):-
    words(Y,X).
translation(X,X).

translate([], []).
translate([H|T], [H1|[' '|T1]]):-
             translation(H, H1),
             translate(T,T1).

prolist([],[]).
prolist(SL,[W|T]):-
    split(SL,WL,R),
    name(W,WL),
    prolist(R,T).

split([],[],[]).
split([32|T],[],T).
split([H|T],[H|T2],R):-
    split(T,T2,R).  

run:-
    nl,write('Enter One sentence or word (English or Malay):'),
    read(X),end(X),
    nl.

end(X):-    
    X=q->write('SESSION END. THANK YOU. ');
    name(X,SL),prolist(SL,List),translate(List,W),cat(W,Disp,_),
    nl,
    write('Translated as:'),
    write(Disp),
    nl,
    run.
```

the output will be the same.