# how to translate 'Saya' to ' I ' and 'saya' to ' i ' in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

when user input **'saya suka makan pisang'** this program will translate the input based on the fact, which means it will translate to **'i like eat banana'**.(the 'i' is lower case)

If the input is not recognized by the program(the input does not match with the existed fact), the program will remain unrecognized words and display it as output. Example, user input **'saya suka makan Pisang'**, output **'i like eat Pisang'** (Pisang is not in my fact)

now what I intend to do is when user input **' Saya suka makan pisang'**,
the program will translate it as **'I like eat banana'**('I' is upper case)

In another words, this program need able to translate all the fact in upper and lower case.

```
words(saya,i).
words(makan,eat).
words(pisang,banana).
words(oren,orange).
words(minum,drink).
words(suka,like).

:- style_check(-singleton).

translation(X,Y):-
    words(X,Y).

translation(X,Y):-
    words(Y,X).

translation(X,X).

translate([], []).

translate([H|T], [H1|T1]):-
             translation(H, H1),
             translate(T,T1).

prolist([],[]).

prolist(SL,[W|T]):-
    split(SL,WL,R),
    name(W,WL),
    prolist(R,T).

split([],[],[]).

split([32|T],[],T).

split([H|T],[H|T2],R):-
    split(T,T2,R).  

run:-
    nl,write('Enter One sentence or word (English or Malay):'),
    read(X),end(X),
    nl.

end(X):-    
X=q->write('SESSION END. THANK YOU. ');
name(X,SL),prolist(SL,List),translate(List,K), atomic_list_concat(K, ' ', W),
nl,
write('Translated as:'),
write(W),
nl,
run.
```

**input output**
[image: input output]

Comment: no, i want to make 'I' translate to 'Saya' and 'i' will translate to 'saya'

Comment: i know I is usually upper case, but in prolog fact we cannot put upper case right?

Comment: u means writing a fact like
words("saya,i")?

Comment: can you write me some code pls?

Comment: I post it in my question already

Comment: @A.A. this is not true, you can put single quotes around anything to make it an atom, including upper case characters.

Comment: `words('Saya','I').` is a completely legitimate way to handle your situation, and produces upper case atoms `Saya` and `I`. These are not strings, `upcase_atom/2` is not needed.

Comment: @DanielLyons i tried your solution,  and it works perfectly!!! tqvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "solution" is to add the capitalized words to your `words/2` table:

```
words(saya,i).
words('Saya', 'I').
words(makan,eat).
words('Makan', 'Eat').
% and so on
```

You can use single quotes around any literal to make it an atom.

This is the cheapest way out for you at the moment.

If you had a large word list then you might need to do something more complicated. For example, you could convert to lower case before using `words/2`, then after you have matched the translated word, capitalize it if necessary. But all this really depends on the use case and it will be more code when the list of words is so small.